# Making rockets lighter using rotational energy

Tags: thermodynamics, rotational-dynamics

I feel like this is trying to cheat physics somehow, I don't think this would work at all, and it's probably not rocket science, but I'd like to have it explained why.

In the ActionLab video here, the video creator demonstrates how something can temporarily be made to seem lighter to a pair of scales by applying rotational energy to part of its mass. I'm still not exactly sure how this works.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwx12kwgOAM&t=132s

My question is, if we are trying to get rockets into space and a major problem is the weight of the rocket, why not offset as much of the rocket's mass as possible using cylinders inside the rocket's body that can be spun up before launch?

Edit: I took another look, and averaged over time, the device demonstrated by ActionLab does not actually seem magically 'lighter' to the scales. What is really happening is the 'lost' downward force is compressed into a single moment when the cylinder reaches the bottom of its trajectory and bounces upwards.

This happens over such a short period of time that the digital scale does not register it.

So my hypothetical rocket would need to get all it can out of the initial falling period, before the first 'bounce' of the cylinders.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with rotation. Things are weightless during free fall. Obviously you can't make a rocket that you want to launch up be in free fall.

Answer (score 0):

The vector sum of all forces on a body equals the mass times the acceleration of the center of mass (CM) of the body, regardless of any rotational motion of the body.

With the mass not falling the CM is stationary, and the force of gravity down equals the force of constraint (from the scale) up.  With the mass moving downwards, the force of gravity down exceeds force of constraint (up) so the scale shows less "weight". Similarly, for a ball initially at rest at the top, when dropped, will result in a smaller force from the scale.

To move the rocket the force of gravity must be overcome regardless of any rotational motion of the rocket.